# Линейный поиск в массиве java

Tags: java

Почему на консоль не выводится индекс найденного слова?

Пользователь вводит слово. Программа ищет в массиве и выводит на экран его индекс:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MassiveStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово: ");
        String object = scn.nextLine();
        String[] word = { "Масло", "Вода", "Дерево", "Кефир", "Помидор", "Сельдерей", "Кувшин" };
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (word[i] == object)
                System.out.print("Ваш индекс" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сравнения строк в яве нужно использовать метод `.equals()`:

```
if (word[i].equals(object))
```

А `word[i] == object` сравнивает один и тот же объект `word[i]` и `object` или разные. Очевидно, что разные.

Comment: Где вы вообще увидели метод `isEquals` - такого метода в `java` не существует, есть метод `equals()`

Comment: @And Да сам понятия не имею, откуда-то взялось в голове. Уже исправил :)

Comment: isEmpty есть , но не isEquals

Comment: Спасибо всем за молниеносную помощь:) !

Comment: @And ``isEqual()`` есть в классе [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-)

Comment: `isEqual` но не `isEquals`, это во первых, а во вторых - это никакого отношения не имеет к сравнению строк.

Comment: @And  Я и писал isEqual. isEquals это вы уже сами придумали. Что касается во-вторых, то во-первых, это говорит о том, что такой метод есть, а во-вторых, отвечает на вопрос откуда я его взял. Перепуталось два похожих в голове, ничего страшного, случается.

Comment: `isEquals` вы писали. Эх, жаль не осталось старой странички. Хотя была (закрыл). Можем поднять этот вопрос, если конечно модераторы смогут поднять старый снимок вашего ответа.